# How to add a comment to post? PostDetailVew, Django 2.1.5

Tags: python, django

I want add comment to post on his page ("post detail" page).

I was find answer, but it create comment on other page. I want create comment on page of "post detail".

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/create/$', views.CommentCreate.as_view(), name='comment_create'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    description = RichTextUploadingField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-comment_date"]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.description)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['description']
```

**views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post


class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['description']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post'] = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post=get_object_or_404(Post, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(CommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],})
```

**comment_form.html**

```
...    
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
...
```

**post_detail.html**

```
...
{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
<p>{{ comment.author }} ({{ comment.comment_date }}) {{ comment.description|safe }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<hr>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p><a href = "{% url 'comment_create' post.id %}">Add a new comment</a></p>
...
```

I think, "comment_form" need to redirect to "post_detail", not generate new page for comment form.

And сould you tell, which parameters has a RichTextField (CKE), how change width, height field only in comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the comment form right in your detail page then all you have to do is to add the form and post function in your View,

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'yourdetailpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['commentform'] = CommentForm()
       return context

    def post(self, request, pk):
       post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
       form = CommentForm(request.POST)

       if form.is_valid():
           obj  = form.save(commit=False)
           obj.post = post
           obj.author = self.request.user
           obj.save()
           return redirect('detail', post.pk)
```

And now you can add your form in your html. And add a submit button to post comment.

Comment: Not working. I **added your code** to views, **removed CommentCreate**, **added code** from _"comment_from.html"_ to _"post_detail.html"_. As a result, to page added only "submit" button, without textarea.

Comment: Have you used this line `{% for form in commentform %}`?

Comment: Sory. It's work. Just need change **form.as_table** to **commentform.as_table** in _comment form_.